# why anchor tag is not working with :after or :before pseudo class?

Tags: html, css

Not working with the anchor(a href) tag.
I want to apply this ">" content after morer id that is after MORE.

```css
#morer a:after {
  content: " >";
  height: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a id="logo" href="#">MASHABLE </a>
  <a href="#">VIDEO </a>
  <a href="#">ENTERTAINMENT </a>
  <a href="#">CULTURE </a>
  <a href="#">TECH </a>
  <a href="#">SCIENCE </a>
  <a href="#">BUSINESS </a>
  <a id="morer" href="#">MORE </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Try this: `#morer:after {...}`.

Comment: selector should be  `a#morer:after`

Answer (score 2):

Your selector should be

```
#morer:after
```

This will look for

```
<element id="morer" :after>
```

Not:

```
#morer a:after
```

And this is looking for

```
<element id="morer">
  …
    <a :after>
```

Working example

```css
#morer:after {
  content: " >";
  height: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a id="logo" href="#">MASHABLE </a>
  <a href="#">VIDEO </a>
  <a href="#">ENTERTAINMENT </a>
  <a href="#">CULTURE </a>
  <a href="#">TECH </a>
  <a href="#">SCIENCE </a>
  <a href="#">BUSINESS </a>
  <a id="morer" href="#">MORE </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: @RohanMahajan i can see te ``>`` after the ``MORE`` link. What are you looking for?

Comment: @RohanMahajan Hope this is what you were looking for. Please do not forget to upvote and accepting the answer unless you still need something else. In that case I'll be more than happy to help you.

Comment: GERARDO BLANCO  I DO

Comment: @RohanMahajan sorry, you do?

Answer (score 1):

`#morer a:after` is looking for an anchor tag **after** the `#morer` element.

Try revising your css declaration to:

```
a#morer:after {
content:" >";
height:10px;
width:20px;
color:black;
}
```

The `a` was moved before the `id` to allow both the `attribute` and `id` to be used in the single declaration.